# USB not working for CM4S

Tags: usb, troubleshooting, compute-module-3, compute-module-4

I used to work with CM3+ and I recently got some CM4S. I have an issue with it and I don't know what to think about it.

**Previous setup:**

I have a [Compute Module IO Board Plus](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/Compute_Module_IO_Board_Plus) designed by WaveShare. When I'm plugging in a CM3+, USB works fine. I also have a board I designed that has the same [schematic](https://files.waveshare.com/upload/7/75/CM3-board.pdf) as the WaveShare. USB communication works as well when I plug in a CM3+.

**Current Problem:**

I'm using this same setup with a CM4S. Since the pinout is the same on the SODIMM connector, I think that no modification is needed. I'm able to communicate in USB with the CM4S when it's plugged into the WaveShare. However, if I'm plugging this same CM4S into my board I can't communicate at all. I have no idea why, CM3+ is working on both boards so I guess the hardware is working well. CM4 is working only on the WaveShare but this is enough for me to conclude that this is not a software issue.

**Troubleshooting:**
I measured the voltage level on my VCC_USB, D+ and D- on each compute module when they are plugged in my customized board :

VCC_USB is 5V in both cases, D+ is 3,5V in both case **BUT** D- is **1,2V** for the CM3+ and **0V** for the CM4S.

I don't know if this is my problem or just a consequence of it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the issue was.

On the datasheet of the WaveShare there is a pull-down without any specific explanation:

[image]

On the datasheet of the CM3+, the pin USB_OTGID is specified but not explained either.
Despite that on the datasheet of the [CM4S](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/cm4s/cm4s-datasheet.pdf) this pin is clearly explained :
[image]

So to make my circuit work, I had to pulldown the pin USB_OTGID.

This modification does not modify the behavior of the [CM3+](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/cm/cm3-plus-datasheet.pdf).